# Delphi: Wait for threads to finish

Tags: multithreading, delphi, threadpool

I read this article about creating a thread pool:
http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/a/delphi-thread-pool-example-using-asynccalls.htm

The reason I use the author's version is because of the waitAll function he made. This is working OK except for the fact that calling waitAll blocks the GUI thus losing the idea of using threads. Any hint/tip on what's needs to be changed? I emailed the author but he didn't respond.

I thought of adding Application.ProcessMessages; in the waiting loop but I don't think it's a good idea. Thanks

Comment: AsyncCalls is no longer supported. As an alternative you might be interested in OmniThreadLibrary. It comes with a lot more documentation and examples for different use cases.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that waiting for all threads to finish in the background is supported? After making ASyncCalls work for me (except for the small problem), I prefer not to adapt this one just to encounter the same problem.

Comment: Do the `WaitAll` inside a thread and when ready, post a message to the main thread. (Perhaps using `TAsyncCalls.VCLInvoke()`.

Comment: I'll try this idea but it's funny that I need to use my own thread in order to handle the sophisticated thread pool mechanism :)

Comment: @Amos, it is not funny at all. The threading paradigm means that you have to make your program event driven. Never wait in the main thread. My threading framework makes sure you can't execute a `WaitAll` function from the main thread.

Answer (score 6):

Waiting for all tasks to complete in the GUI thread is the wrong way to do it. Don't do that.

Instead arrange for each task to signal completion to the main thread. When the main thread receives the final completion signal, it can perform whatever task is needed to executed. You might make a counter of all the tasks that are to run. Each task that completes signals the main thread which decrements the count. When it reaches zero they are all done

Or create another background thread with the sole task of waiting on all the other tasks. That's fine in a background thread as it won't block the UI. When that wait completes, send a message to the UI thread.

Comment: I understand the theory of how to do it and AsyncCalls do exactly that so I don't want to re-invent the wheel. The author of the article already added the waitAll function but I guess I just need to use it correctly.

Comment: Exactly what? There are two quite different options in my answer.

Comment: My bad, someone else also wrote about creating a dedicated thread to wait for everything to finish so I mixed things up. I will try the counter idea and update. Thanks. I guess it means I shouldn't use the waitAll of the author.

Comment: @Amos You can use `waitAll` but **do not use** it in the main thread!

Comment: Ofcourse but as I wrote above: it's funny that I need to use my own thread in order to handle the sophisticated thread pool mechanism :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you like I would add that pseudo code to your answer and delete mine

Comment: @Amos That is the same as in real life "Buy something to eat, clean the car and tell me if all is done." - You now have three tasks to do (two working tasks and one reporting task)

Comment: @SirRufo Nice translation to real world, makes sense! One small difference the reporting task (tell me if all is done) isn't started before you start the other 2 tasks (at least it doesn't feel like that). Somewhere in your memory is a flag to execute that task as soon as you finish the working tasks.

Answer (score 4):

The simple pattern for task creation and waiting until the work is done is shown by this pseudo code

```
// create a management task
task.Create(
  procedure
  var
    tasks : TArray<task>;
  begin
    // synchronized action to the main thread
    // before the work begins
    TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      SomeForm.Button.Enabled := False;
    end);

    // creation of the tasks doing the real work
    tasks := ...

    // wait until the work is done
    WaitForAll( tasks );

    // synchronized action to the main thread
    // after the work hs finished
    TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      SomeForm.Button.Enabled := True;
    end);
  end );
```

And this is just a pseudo code translation of davids answer (second part).